# Does upgrading your phone/network take effect immediately?

Tags: hack-ex

In the game 'Hack:EX', you can do multiple processes at a time: cracking passwords, hacking phones, or uploading/downloading software. While you're waiting, and you decide to purchase an upgrade, such as from 2GS to 3G network speed, does the change happen right away, or when you go and start another task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that after buying the upgrades, I had about 15 processes immediately complete, so I'm assuming it takes effect immediately

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had everything in my que complete successfully when I leveled once, even things that had 50+ days. But yes...the hardware upgrades take effect immediately